# Why foreach loop does not work with datagridview selected rows in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to c# and using windows forms.

The following code loops through all selected rows in `datagridview` and take variables from cell0 and 4 as condition to use in sql query.

I multi-select rows then use this code and when I check the result in sql table I find this code only consider the first selected row in datagridview and ignore the rest.

Anyone knows how can I fix it, or what I am doing wrong? please help , thank you

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV.SelectedRows)
                {



                OrderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(DGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
                OrderDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value);

                MyConnection.Open();
                MyCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE List_of_All_Orders set Delivery_State=@_Delivery_State WHERE Order_Number=@_OrderNumber and Date_Time_Ordered =@_OrderDateTime";

                MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

                MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@_Delivery_State", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = button7.Text;
                MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@_OrderNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrderNumber;
                MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@_OrderDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = OrderDateTime;

                MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MyCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                MyConnection.Close();



                }
```

Comment: Replace `DGV.SelectedRows[0]` with `row`

Comment: @ Ivan Stoev , it worked tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I multi-select rows then use this code and when I check the result in
>   sql table I find this code only consider the first selected row in
>   datagridview and ignore the rest.

That's *too* normal because you use *same* row cell as `DGV.SelectedRows[0]` in every iteration, not the rows that you iterate.

Change your

```
OrderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(DGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
OrderDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value);
```

to

```
OrderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
OrderDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[4].Value);
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command *automatically* instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

```
using(var MyConnection = new MySqlConnection(conString))
using(var MyCommand = MyConnection.CreateCommand())
{
     MyCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE List_of_All_Orders set Delivery_State=@_Delivery_State WHERE Order_Number=@_OrderNumber and Date_Time_Ordered =@_OrderDateTime";
     MyConnection.Open();  

     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV.SelectedRows)
     {
        MyCommand.Parameters.Clear();

        OrderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
        OrderDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[4].Value);

        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_Delivery_State", button7.Text);
        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_OrderNumber", OrderNumber);
        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_OrderDateTime", OrderDateTime);

        MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

I used `AddWithValue` in my example but you [don't use this method](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload as you did with *proper* `MySqlDbType`, not `SqlDbType`.